# Google Apps Script & Sheets - do I have to share with full read/write?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have an apps script ([here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwIYSOsqlTL_2lx9oD-xIK2ag9u_bbKG-Z3UnkQfr4wDBkuvzsk/exec), if you want to play with it) that accesses a spreadsheet.  For MOST stuff, all it does is reads the sheet...

However...

I want to let users store some data.  Basically, I have the script picking up their email addresses and using that to create a page in my spreadsheet...

Unfortunately, of course, doing so requires that they be given read/write access to the sheet... and in the interest of protecting users' data, I'd rather not do that.

But, is it even possible to both:

1. Extend read/write access (for a sheet) to my app itself WITHOUT making the sheet public, AND
2. Still have access to user's email address?

Things I've learned in this process:

- I can't access a user's email address if I deploy the app to run as me.
- an API key is only useful for public data

I initialize pages in my doGet routine.  I packaged getting the username and related sheets in a function so that I could easily swap out placeholders for email addresses while I was testing.  The following code works fine for me since I'm the authenticated user:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (!e.parameter.page) {
    var userCrewSheetName = getUserSheetName();
    var userCrewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(userCrewSheetName);
    initializeSheet(userCrewSheet,userCrewSheetName);
    var userBonusSheetName = getUserSheetName("bonus");
    var userBonusSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(userBonusSheetName);
    initializeSheet(userBonusSheet,userBonusSheetName);
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test').evaluate();
  }
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page']).evaluate();
}

function initializeSheet(sheet,sheetName) {
  if(sheet == null) { 
    sheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
    sheet.setName(sheetName);
    setHeaders(sheet,sheetName);
  }
}

function getUserSheetName(sheetType) {
  var userName = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  if (!userName) { return };
  if(sheetType == "bonus") {
    return userName + '_my_bonus';
  } else {
    return userName + '_my_crew';
  }
  return "error";
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code in the question itself?

Comment: edited to add that in

Comment: Looks like I'll need to sort through all of the API Key / Oath2 Authentication stuff at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

Been there buddy. If I understand your question correctly, you want your webapp to be able to detect user IDs and allow them to read data from it and also allow in some cases for them to store data onto it.

Your answer is that you need to publish your webapp again with RunAs: Me. This way, you will still be able to capture user IDs, allow them to read data and write data as well, without having direct edit access to your Spreadsheet as the webApp is being accessed as you. Cheers!!

Comment: Hmmm... The method I currently use to capture them shouldn't work in that case, because the documentation for getActiveUser says it would return my email address instead of theirs if I use run as: me

Comment: Try it friend, you will be surprised. I have more than 20 webapps to suggest that in which I have set the execution as me so that nobody else can make any changes directly on the spreadsheet but it still captures their email addresses and allows them to read/right data to the spreadsheet via webapp interface. :)

Comment: Sadly... no, it returns "undefined" when I do a Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

Comment: would love to see one of those sample apps

Comment: I just replicated this scenario and clearly I was wrong. Really sorry for that. The webapps that I had created were in a G-Suite account, so may be that's why it was capturing IDs anyway. :(

Comment: Yeah... there's got to be some way to do this, through API Keys and such... may take a while to figure it out